# Is is possible to enable metabase compatibility in IIS 7 programmatically?

Tags: iis-7, installation, installshield, iis-metabase

I have an application that I am wrapping up in an installer. I would like to, either through the registry, or by writing a script, enable IIS 6 metabase compatibility in IIS 7.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Are you targeting just Windows 2008 server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use dism.exe or [pkgmgr.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749465%28WS.10%29.aspx) or [ocsetup.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766272%28WS.10%29.aspx) to automate the installation of this component.  You can technically do this these days because Windows Vista ( as far as I know ) always caches the WIM file needed to install the component.

Still, I wouldn't do it.  I'd just upgrade to InstallShield 2010 which has native II7 capabilities.  Or you could use Windows Installer XML 3.5 which has the same.    You eliminate the dependency and simplify the deployment in the process.

If you decide to do it anyways, check out this good article:

[Install Typical IIS Workloads](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/136/install-typical-iis-workloads/)

> **UI Name Update Name**
>
> IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility 
>   IIS-Metabase
>
> IIS 6 WMI Compatibility
>
> IIS-WMICompatibility    IIS 6
>
> Scripting Tools IIS-LegacyScripts

Comment: I actually just downloaded a trial version of that this morning. Thanks.